# Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'trix' does not provide an export named 'default' (at youtube.js:1:8) in rails 7.1 when trying to edit trix

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-7, trix, actiontext

I am currently facing an issue when I try to configure the actiontext editor in rails 7.1.3 to handle YouTube videos embedded.

Currently running rails 7.1.3, ruby 3.2.0, and using importmaps.

(Following Chris Oliver's excellent example https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2iGBuLQ3S0c
There is a written guide here - https://dev.to/superails/ruby-on-rails-embed-youtube-videos-with-actiontext-tldr-3m35)

I am getting this error - Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module 'trix' does not provide an export named 'default' (at youtube.js:1:8)
The error is understandable, but I don't know how to fix it.

In my youtube.js file I import trix like this.

```
import Trix from "trix"
import Rails from "@rails/ujs" 

let lang = Trix.config.lang;
Trix.config.toolbar = {
  getDefaultHTML: function() {
    return `
    <div class="trix-button-row">
.....
```

I tried without luck to change it to

`import * as Trix from "trix"`

When I look into the trix.js, I do see an export:

`export{Wn as default};`

My importmap.rb looks like this:

## Pin npm packages by running ./bin/importmap

```
pin "application"
pin "@hotwired/turbo-rails", to: "turbo.min.js", preload: true
pin "@hotwired/stimulus", to: "stimulus.min.js"
pin "@hotwired/stimulus-loading", to: "stimulus-loading.js"
pin_all_from "app/javascript/controllers", under: "controllers"
pin "@rails/actiontext", to: "actiontext.esm.js"
pin "@rails/ujs", to: "@rails--ujs.js" # @7.1.3
pin "trix" # @2.0.10
```

Has anyone experienced this issue before?  And maybe found a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pin "trix"` links to a UMD build which doesn't have any exports, it only exposes Trix [globally](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.1.3.2/actiontext/app/assets/javascripts/trix.js#L12098). That means `import "trix"` is all you need. This build is meant to work with plain sprockets as well:

*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/actiontext/app/assets/javascripts/trix.js*

On the other hand, ESM build has a default export:
*https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/trix@2.0.10/dist/trix.esm.js*

---

```rb
>> Rails.application.assets.find_asset("trix").filename
=> "/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/actiontext-7.1.3/app/assets/javascripts/trix.js"
```

If you've pinned `trix` separately into your vendor directory (which would be esm build), it won't change anything because vendor is all the way at the end of the assets paths:

```rb
>> Rails.application.assets.paths
=> 
["/home/alex/code/stackoverflow/app/assets/builds",
 "/home/alex/code/stackoverflow/app/assets/config",
...
 "/home/alex/.rbenv/versions/3.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.3.0/gems/actiontext-7.1.3/app/assets/javascripts",
...
 "/home/alex/code/stackoverflow/vendor/javascript"]  # <= gets searched last
```

This is the best I could figure out to fix the order:

```rb
# config/initializers/assets.rb

Rails.application.config.after_initialize do |app|
  # https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/v4.2.1/lib/sprockets/paths.rb#L37
  app.assets.prepend_path Rails.root.join("vendor/javascript")
end
```

```rb
>> Rails.application.assets.find_asset("trix").filename
=> "/home/alex/code/stackoverflow/vendor/javascript/trix.js"
```

---

Changing your pin to jspm url also can fix this, however url pins are no longer a thing by default in `importmap-rails v2`, so this is a manual copy-paste operation:

```rb
# config/importmap.rb

pin "trix", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:trix@2.0.10/dist/trix.esm.min.js"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
I do seem to struggle to understand how the best way to extend or edit the functionality of actiontext / trix?
I am trying to add the option to embed youtube, but I guess I need to import the trix.js inside the javascript file and then edit or extend it?
Or am i taking the wrong approach here?

Comment: yes, `import "trix";` then you'll have a global `Trix` that you can modify. last i checked, that was the only approach.

Comment: Thank you!
I am not sure how to modify it in the js file when Trix is not available


``` 
import "trix"
import Rails from "@rails/ujs" 

let lang = Trix.config.lang;
Trix.config.toolbar = {
  getDefaultHTML: function() {
    return `
    <div class="trix-button-row">
      <span class="trix-button-group trix-button-group--text-tools" data-trix-button-group="text-tools">
.....
```

Trix.config.toolbar isnt avaliable when I just do import "trix";

Comment: you mean your editor tells you it's not available? it's a global constant, so it's available everywhere. works fine for me with either umd or esm builds. you could also: `pin "trix", to: "https://ga.jspm.io/npm:trix@2.0.10/dist/trix.esm.min.js"` to use `import Trix from "trix"`

Comment: Ah now I get it.  Thank you! :)
It works when I pin it to the ga.jspm.io...
I do get a new error though:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'toolbar' of object '[object Object]'

Comment: try `Trix.config.toolbar.getDefaultHTML = function () {`